# Having Trouble Creating Second Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, composite-key

Below is my code:

```
if ($employee !== FALSE) {
    echo " ";
} else {
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE employee (EID SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    fname VARCHAR(20), lname VARCHAR(20), phone VARCHAR(15), email VARCHAR(30))") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("ALTER TABLE employee AUTO_INCREMENT=001");
}
//ticket table creation
if ($ticket !== FALSE) {
    echo " ";
} else {
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE ticket (TickID SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, EID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
                                    INDEX fk_empID(EID), FOREIGN KEY (EID) REFERENCES employee(EID), time_date VARCHAR(20),
                                    problem LONGTEXT, updates LONGTEXT, location VARCHAR(25), completed VARCHAR(5))ENGINE=INNODB") or die(mysql_error());
}
//ticket assignment intermediary table creation
if ($ticket_assign !== FALSE) {
    echo " ";
} else {
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE assignment (TechID SMALLINT, TickID SMALLINT, PRIMARY KEY (TechID, TickID),
    INDEX fks_assgn(TickID, TechID), FOREIGN KEY(TechID) REFERENCES ticket(TechID))ENGINE=INNODB") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("ALTER TABLE assignment (ADD CONSTRAINT fk_assgn FOREIGN KEY(TickID) REFERENCES ticket(TickID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE) ENGINE=INNODB") or die(mysql_error());
}
//technician table creation
if ($technician !== FALSE) {
    echo " ";   
} else {
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE technician (TechID SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                    fname VARCHAR(20), lname VARCHAR(20), phone VARCHAR(15), email VARCHAR(30))");
}
```

I am attempting to add two foreign keys to the assignment table and I keep getting an error saying that the page "cannot add foreign key constraint".

What am I missing? I feel as though it is something simple, but I will take any advice given.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. Turns out you can't set something as a foreign key before the table has been made.

Moved technician table above assignment table and the error went away.